# Why is my jasmine unit test not waiting for 'done'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I have the test in my node application...

```
it('will call done', function(done) {
            myObj.fn(function(){

                done();
           }
});
```

and the code....

```
myObj.fn = function(success){
   setTimeout(2000000000,success);
}
```

When I run the test I get this in the output...

```
-MacBook-Pro:torus-pqdata user$ npm test

> torus-pqdata@0.0.0 test /Stuff/code bases/2015/torus-pqdata
> jasmine-node specs/
```

However as you can see the unit test just exits without failing but I need it to timeout (I am trying to simulate something hanging). How do I get it to timeout?

Comment: Args in the setTimeout are the wrong way around. Callback first, then the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the arguments in setTimeout:

```
myObj.fn = function(success){
    setTimeout(success, 200000000);
}
```

Here's some reference from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout